# Rails 5.2 application secrets empty at Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I deployed to Heroku with success but there is an issue with credentials.
I added `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` env variable at Heroku app CONFIG VARS section and copy-pasted the value from my app `master.key` file:
[image]

Then when I check its value from Heroku console, it is still nil:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 5.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> Rails.application.secrets
=> {:secret_key_base=>nil, :secret_token=>nil}
irb(main):003:0>
```

But when I check it other way:

```
ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY']
=> "sdfghjklm.......1a0befa6139"
```

it is displayed correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

I figured out myself, - I followed a [Pluralsight tutorial](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api) on Rails API and it used the old way to get Rails secrets:

```
Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base
```

Starting from Rails 5.2 there is no more `secrets.yml` file and the right way to get the env variables saved in `credential.yml.enc`is as follows:

```
Rails.application.credentials.dig(:secret_key_base)
```

After updating the corresponding code, everything works as needed. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```rb
SECRET = Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base
```

to:

```rb
SECRET = ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] || Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base
```

worked for me. 
`ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE']` worked in production environment while `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base` worked in development environment.