# Rails REST Api auth error statud code 500 in heroku but not in local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, axios

Made a ror api with auth and JWT to feed a react app. In dev environment (localhost) everything was working fine. Once I deployed to heroku I started to have that error. I deployed following heroku's rails docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5

When I try to "signup" or "signing" the request fails with status code 500. What is really weird is that in the heroku rails console the user is created, but i'm not getting my token back in json. This is the call from my react app:

```
axios.post('https://hidden-ocean-49877.herokuapp.com/signup', {withCredentials: true,
        name: name, email: email, password: password, password_confirmation: passwordConfirmation})
            .then(response => {
                login(true);
                tokenize(response.data.auth_token);
            }).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

this is the log in heroku log:

```
2020-02-29T21:43:16.041318+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signup" host=hidden-ocean-49877.herokuapp.com request_id=7cd577ad-c7c5-4fa7-aa99-91b4b8e49772 fwd="189.214.5.88" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=977ms status=500 bytes=421 protocol=https
2020-02-29T21:43:16.038685+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-29T21:43:16.038582 #4]  INFO -- : [7cd577ad-c7c5-4fa7-aa99-91b4b8e49772] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 925ms (ActiveRecord: 29.5ms)
2020-02-29T21:43:16.039125+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-02-29T21:43:16.039063 #4] FATAL -- : [7cd577ad-c7c5-4fa7-aa99-91b4b8e49772]
2020-02-29T21:43:16.039179+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-02-29T21:43:16.039120 #4] FATAL -- : [7cd577ad-c7c5-4fa7-aa99-91b4b8e49772] TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
2020-02-29T21:43:16.039221+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-02-29T21:43:16.039178 #4] FATAL -- : [7cd577ad-c7c5-4fa7-aa99-91b4b8e49772]
2020-02-29T21:43:16.039264+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-02-29T21:43:16.039226 #4] FATAL -- : [7cd577ad-c7c5-4fa7-aa99-91b4b8e49772] app/lib/json_web_token.rb:9:in `encode'
2020-02-29T21:43:16.039264+00:00 app[web.1]: [7cd577ad-c7c5-4fa7-aa99-91b4b8e49772] app/auth/authenticate_user.rb:9:in `call'
2020-02-29T21:43:16.039264+00:00 app[web.1]: [7cd577ad-c7c5-4fa7-aa99-91b4b8e49772] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

The files that are described above are this ones:

User controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorize_request, only: :create

    def create
        user = User.create!(user_params)
        auth_token = AuthenticateUser.new(user.email, user.password).call
        response = { message: Message.account_created, auth_token: auth_token }
        json_response(response, :created)
      end

      private

      def user_params
        params.permit(
          :name,
          :email,
          :password,
          :password_confirmation
        )
      end
end
```

in app/auth/authenticate_user.rb:

```
class AuthenticateUser
    def initialize(email, password)
      @email = email
      @password = password
    end

    # Service entry point
    def call
      JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: user.id) if user
    end

    private

    attr_reader :email, :password


    def user
      user = User.find_by(email: email)
      return user if user && user.authenticate(password)
      raise(ExceptionHandler::AuthenticationError, Message.invalid_credentials)
    end
  end
```

in app/lib/json_web_token.rb:

```
class JsonWebToken
    # secret to encode and decode token
    HMAC_SECRET = Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base

    def self.encode(payload, exp = 24.hours.from_now)
      # set expiry to 24 hours from creation time
      payload[:exp] = exp.to_i
      # sign token with application secret
      JWT.encode(payload, HMAC_SECRET)
    end

    def self.decode(token)
      # get payload; first index in decoded Array
      body = JWT.decode(token, HMAC_SECRET)[0]
      HashWithIndifferentAccess.new body
      # rescue from all decode errors
    rescue JWT::DecodeError => e
      # raise custom error to be handled by custom handler
      raise ExceptionHandler::InvalidToken, e.message
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the stack trace, the error happens in `app/lib/json_web_token.rb#9`. I suspect that the error happens in:

```
HMAC_SECRET = Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base
```

then raises a type error in:

```
JWT.encode(payload, HMAC_SECRET)
```

Is it possible that your version of rails uses a new way for fetching `secret_key_base` as described here: [Rails 5.2 application secrets empty at Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889272/rails-5-2-application-secrets-empty-at-heroku)

Try running `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base` in prod console and see if it returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use instead

```
HMAC_SECRET = Rails.application.secret_key_base
```

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/4864